# Why does the output of the secret from the kubernetes job not show the actual value?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

Can anyone tell me why the out put of this job come out as not text?

[Job.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBTtY.png)

the output is �ǫ when its supposed to be user

the secret looks like this: [Secret.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnVCV.png)

Comment: Please refrain from using images, use the text. This will help folks copy and try out your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the secret value was not base64 encoded during creation. Use `stringData` for un-encoded value:

```
...
stringData:
  username: user
  password: password
```

Comment: I would add this is the link to the docs that give some great info https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configmap-secret/managing-secret-using-config-file/#create-the-config-file